# React Native WebView load only a section of a html webpage

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-native

I need to load on WebView a part of a webpage, like a div. is it possible?

for example

```
  <WebView
      source={{uri: 'https://www.amazon.com/'}}
      style={{marginTop: 20}}
  />
```

with a div: `id="nav-shop"`

how to show only this part?

**I think that the best thing to do is to 'hide' div elements, but i don't how to do that. If someone have some ideas tell me.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Webview has a parameter called `injectJavascript` where you can manipulate the javascript of the Webview you receive.

According to the documentation, you pass the javascript you want to run as a string.

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/webview.html#injectjavascript

Comment: can you show some example. For example I want get only login section of  github.com?